# Is it permissible to use/own silk bed-throws?

Tags: hadith, fatwa

I have read some hadith about silk:

> Abu Musa al-Ash'ari reported that the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, "*Wearing silk and gold has been forbidden for the men of the my community but is lawful for its females.*" [at-Tirmidhi]

And

> Hudhayfa said, "*The Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, forbade us to drink or eat from gold and silver vessels and to wear silk and brocade or sit on them.*" [al-Bukhari]

Does this last hadith prohibit the use of silk in bed throws?

Comment: I wonder how this ruling applies to silk-like polymers. I heard this hadith was due to the Prophet disliking excess luxury, but what about all the cheap plastics today that feel like silk?

Comment: @Muz that would make an excellent question on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It is not permissible to use silk for bed throws, because it is one kind of using silk, which is clearly prohibited.

Al-Haafiz Ibn Hajar (may Allah have mercy on him) said:

> The words and to sit on them are strong proof for those who say that it is not allowed to sit on silk, which is the view of the majority. Ibn Wahb narrated in his Jaami from the hadeeth of Sad ibn Abi Waqqaas that he said: To sit on a live coal is dearer to me than sitting on a seat of silk.

Ibn al-Qayyim (may Allah have mercy on him) said:

> Even if we did not have this text, the prohibition on wearing it would still include using it in furnishings, as it also includes using it as covers or blankets, as the word libs (lit. wearing) includes these meanings in both the linguistic and shari sense; Anas said: I went to a reed mat of ours that had turned black from long use (lit. wearing). Narrated by al-Bukhaari (380) and Muslim (658). Even if the general wording did not imply that the prohibition included using it in furnishings, mere analogy would imply that it was forbidden.

Source: [this question](http://www.islamonline.com/news/articles/141/It-is-haraam-for-a-man-to-wear-natural-silk-or-to-.html)