# Is it allowed to wear silk mixed cotton cloths

Tags: halal-haram, fatwa

It is not allowed for men to wear silk cloths. [Is it permissible to use/own silk bed-throws?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/is-it-permissible-to-use-own-silk-bed-throws). There are men's cloths known as Andi Cotton Punjabi which is quite popular in some areas. In Andi cotton, 5% to 20% silk is mixed. Is such cloth is permissible to wear?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference of opinion regarding this. The hanafi Madhab permits clothing in which there is less than 50% silk.

> In the Hanafi school, it is permitted without dislike to wear items of clothing in which there is less than 50% silk content. [Nahlawi, al-Hadhr wa’l Ibaha]
>
> [Islamqa.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/36689)

But scholars at IslamQA regard all kinds of clothing that have pure silk mixture to be haram except in the following cases and if the mixture is larger than "four fingers’ width" of silk.

> The scholars allowed men to wear silk in certain exceptional
> circumstances where there is shar’i evidence to support this, such as
> Muslim combatants in war who are allowed to wear silk in order to show
> off and annoy the enemy, which is a kind of psychological warfare.
> People who are sick may also be permitted to wear silk to relieve
> their suffering, as Anas reported that the Prophet (peace and
> blessings of Allaah be upon him) allowed ‘Abd al-Rahmaan ibn ‘Awf and
> Ibn al-Zubayr (may Allaah be pleased with them both) to wear silk
> because of a skin irritation that they suffered from. (Reported by
> al-Bukhaari, 10/295, and Muslim, 3/1646).
>
> The scholars also allowed men to wear garments containing four
> fingers’ width of silk, because of the hadeeth of ‘Umar ibn
> al-Khattaab (may Allaah be pleased with him) who said that the Prophet
> (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) forbade the wearing of
> silk except for an area the width of two fingers, or three or four.”
> (Reported by Muslim, 3/1644).
>
> [Islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/2037)

Now, it's up to you to choose between these two different views. You should also keep in mind that the prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “Whoever wears silk in this world will not wear it in the Hereafter.”
> (al-Bukhaari, 5832).

Just a remainder, all kinds of silk are halal for women.

Answer (score 0):

Hadith

حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى عَنْ شُعْبَةَ حَدَّثَنِي أَبُو ذِبْيَانَ سَمِعْتُ عَبْدَ اللَّهِ بْنَ الزُّبَيْرِ يَقُولُ لَا تُلْبِسُوا نِسَاءَكُمْ الْحَرِيرَ فَإِنِّي سَمِعْتُ عُمَرَ يُحَدِّثُ يَقُولُ عَنْ النَّبِيِّ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ أَنَّهُ قَالَ مَنْ لَبِسَ الْحَرِيرَ فِي الدُّنْيَا لَمْ يَلْبَسْهُ فِي الْآخِرَةِ و قَالَ عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ الزُّبَيْرِ مِنْ عِنْدِهِ وَمَنْ لَمْ يَلْبَسْهُ فِي الْآخِرَةِ لَمْ يَدْخُلْ الْجَنَّةَ قَالَ اللَّهُ تَعَالَى [[[{ وَلِبَاسُهُمْ فِيهَا حَرِيرٌ }]]].

Abu Dhibyan told us:

I heard ‘Abdullah bin az-Zubair say: Do not let your women wear silk, for I heard "Umar narrate from the Prophet (ﷺ) that he said: "Whoever wears silk in this world will not wear it in the Hereafter." And "Abdullah bin az-Zubair added his own words: And whoever does not wear it in the Hereafter will not enter Paradise. Allah says: “and their garments therein will be of silk" [Fatir 35:33].

Sahih (Darussalam) [, al-Bukhari (5828) and Muslim (2069)

Musnad Ahmad 251
Arabic/English book : Book 2, Hadith 251
Musnad Ahmed

Get Hadith Collection (All in one) App:https://goo.gl/8j06i9
#GreentechApps #Hadith

Answer (score -1):

Wearing Silk is Haram no matter how much percent.
But if you have a disease on your skin and only silk can help, so its allowed.

Comment: Salaam, and welcome to Islam.SE. We expects answers here to be substantial and backed up by Islamic sources. Please consider improving your answer, and also have a look at [How do I write good answers](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu alaikum,  I was shown a silk blend sherwani for my wedding in Lahore. The shop keeper told me provided it isnt majority silk it is allowed; and that making a halal living was as much a concern for him as it was for us. I asked around and that was the answer I was getting ie a material is only considered to be 'silk' when that is the majority. 
It is established that small amounts of silk can be uesed (up to four fingers length), so threads and baring and patches are fine. 
I don't know if sleeping in bedsheets counts as wearing it.

Comment: Salam and welcome on Islam SE. Please take your time and take our [tour], check our [help] and visit [meta] to learn more about this site. I also recommend you to read [answer] to learn what makes a good answer.